# Why does my DataGridView generate an extra barcode?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I'm currently in the making of creating a inventory program for my thesis in highschool. Took me hours to get the DataGridView to even function properly with my database(SQLite3) now when i go into my form and try looking at the data it generates an additional barcode datacolumn and I have no idea why...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pcevinvprogram
{
public partial class ViewInventoryForm : Form
{
private SQLiteConnection connection;
private SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter;
private DataTable dataTable;

public ViewInventoryForm()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

private void ViewInventoryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Initialize database connection
string connectionString = "Data Source=C:\\Users\\denin\\Desktop\\PCEVINV\\Database_pcevinv\\pcevinv.db;Version=3;";
connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

// Load data into the DataGridView
LoadInventoryData();
}

private void LoadInventoryData()
{
// Create a SELECT query to retrieve one inventory item, including the barcode image
string query = "SELECT ItemName, Description, Quantity, Barcode, BarcodeImage FROM InventoryItems";

dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);
dataTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

// Bind the DataTable to the DataGridView
dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = dataTable;

// Display barcode image in the DataGridView
DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imageColumn.HeaderText = "Barcode Image";
dataGridViewInventory.Columns.Add(imageColumn);

// Assuming there is only one row in the DataTable
if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 1)
{
DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[0];
object cellValue = row["BarcodeImage"];
Console.WriteLine($"CellValue type: {cellValue.GetType().FullName}, CellValue: {cellValue}");

// Attempt to cast the value to a byte array
if (cellValue is byte[] imageBytes)
{
// Check if the byte array is not null or empty
if (imageBytes.Length > 0)
{
dataGridViewInventory.Rows[0].Cells["BarcodeImage"].Value = imageBytes;
}
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Unable to cast to byte[], value is not a byte array.");
}
}

}
private void buttonTakeOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Implement code to take out quantities from selected item
// Update the database and refresh the DataGridView
}

private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Implement code to remove selected item
// Update the database and refresh the DataGridView
}
private void ViewInventoryForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
connection.Close();
}

private void dataGridViewInventory_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
}
}
}
```

I've tried limiting the database retrieval... Specifying what part of the database I want to get. I just can't wrap my head around why it makes 2 data entries called "Barcode"

Comment: You're setting the DataSource of your DGV. If not otherwise specified, the DGV auto-generates Columns of the corresponding Type. The query includes two Columns, `Barcode` and `BarcodeImage`. The latter is probably a `byte[]` (`BLOB`) that represents the image bytes. The DGV then generates a `DataGridViewImageColumn` to present the image data You're adding another of the same Type, manually (with no `DataPropertyName` set, apparently) -- You should not store the Connection object. You should declare and dispose of it in-place.

Comment: Thank you Jimi! Got it working without hiccups now!